# Sonarqube Authentication: Disable Login Field

Tags: authentication, github, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Background: I'm setting up a SonarQube instance for code inspection and I've enabled GitHub Authentication via OAuth. In the spirit of reducing attack vectors, I'd like to remove the username/password login text boxes and functionality. This will force users to only login with GitHub accounts tied to pre-approved organizations.

Is there a property I can set in the sonar.properties file to disable the traditional login form but keep the "Log in with GitHub" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to disable the login/password form because we want you to be able to authenticate with a "local" user (for instance admin) if something go wrong with GitHub and you still want to authenticate an update settings or thinks like that.

Comment: Couldn't admin rights be bestowed to a GitHub user via the SonarQube API? I'm using test-kitchen to provision an instance, and I am already using the API to tweak things here and there.

Comment: Ah, but I would need an API token with admin rights, which would probably be restricted to admin in the first place.

Comment: Accepting your answer @Julien. Thanks for the insight!